# How to get 'left' private property of ngx countdown?

Tags: typescript, timer, properties, angular7, countdown

I can't get the 'left' property from ngx-countdown which is private.

I've read that you are supposed to declare the property as public but this is a library only (ngx-countdown) that I have installed

The error that I get:

ERROR in src/app/pages/exam-levels/exam-level2/exam-level2.component.ts(129,30): error TS2341: Property 'left' is private and only accessible within class 'CountdownComponent'.
src/app/pages/exam-levels/exam-level2/exam-level2.component.ts(130,39): error TS2341: Property 'left' is private and only accessible within class 'CountdownComponent'.

THE TS FILE

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ExamsService } from '@app/services/exams.service';
import { ExamsModel } from '@app/models/exams.model';
import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { ConfirmationModalModel } from '@app/models/confirmation-modal.model';
import { CountdownComponent } from 'ngx-countdown';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-exam-level2',
  templateUrl: './exam-level2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./exam-level2.component.scss']
})
export class ExamLevel2Component implements OnInit {

  remainingTime: any;

  seconds = CountdownComponent['left'];

  public questionsListLevel2: Array<ExamsModel>;
  public examLevel2ModalContent: ConfirmationModalModel;

  public timeLeft: CountdownComponent["left"];

  level2QuestionsSet$: Subscription;
  pageTab: string;

  isToggled: boolean;

  status = '';
  @ViewChild('countdown') counter: CountdownComponent;

  resetTimer() {
    this.counter.restart();
    this.counter.stop();
    this.counter.pause();
    this.counter.resume();
  }

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private examsService: ExamsService,
  ) {
      this.pageTab = "exam-level2";
    }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getQuestionsListPart2();
    this.isToggled = false;
  }




  // TIMER
  finishTest() {
    console.log('count down', this.counter);

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['/exam-level3']);
      }
      , 3000);
  }
  stopTimer () {
    this.counter.pause();
    console.log(this.counter);
    // console.log(this.counter.finished)
    // this.timerService.sayHello();
  }



  onNotify() {
    console.log(this.counter.left);
    this.remainingTime = this.counter.left;

    this.store();
  }

  store(){
    let key = 'Timer';
    localStorage.setItem(key, this.remainingTime);
  }
}
```

---

THE TEMPLATE

```
 <!-- TIMER START -->
        <div class="timer-container">
          <countdown #countdown [config]="{leftTime: 1800, notify: [ 1795 ]}" (finished)="finishTest()" (notify)="onNotify($event)">$!m!:$!s!</countdown>
          <button (click)="stopTimer()" class="btn btn-link btn-sm">STOP</button>
          <button (click)="store()" class="btn btn-link btn-sm">STORE</button>
        </div>
        <!-- TIMER END -->
```

Answer (score 2):

New edit:

when compiling it is showing

[image]

But when I tried to log it, it is showing the value

[image]

[image]

In the HTML you can access like this

```
<countdown #cnt [config]="{leftTime: 360 * 10}">$!m!:$!s!</countdown>
  <br>
  {{cnt.left}}
```

[image: Live]

Answer (score 1):

You can access by the event, in my case.

HTML:

```html
<countdown [config]="config" (event)="onEvent($event)">
```

Typescript:

```
onEvent($event): void {
    let timeLeft = $event.left;
}
```

With the notify event it must be the same. In this way you can access without errors from being private